# Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting an error

> "ForwardRef(InputBase) contains an input of type text with both value and defaultValue props. Input elements must be either controlled or uncontrolled (specify either the value prop, or the defaultValue prop, but not both). Decide between using a controlled or uncontrolled input element and remove one of these props."

I have located the source of the bug to this piece of code `(defaultValue="" to be specific)`. I was wondering how can I solve it without deleting `defaultValue=""`?

```
                <CustomInput
                  type="text"
                  onChange={props.handleChange}
                  onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                  value={props.values.search}
                  id="outlined-size-small"
                  defaultValue=""
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                  name="search"
                  label="Search"
                  disabled={props.isSubmitting}
                />
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `defaultValue` props of the input to `props.values.search` and initiate the `props.values.search` it to an empty string `""` like how you are currently doing currently.

Comment: like this? 
`<CustomInput
      type="text"
       onChange={props.handleChange}
       onBlur={props.handleBlur}
       value=""
       id="outlined-size-small"
       defaultValue={props.values.search}
       variant="outlined"
       size="small"
       name="search"
       label="Search"
       disabled={props.isSubmitting}
        />`

Comment: Yes that looks correct. Be sure initialize the `props.value.search` to an empty string `""` at where it is initialized

Comment: Thank you for responding, I am not quite sure what you mean by "Be sure initialize the props.value.search to an empty string "" at where it is initialized" can you provide a code example?

Comment: Can I see how do you pass in the value.search props? Probably a snipper of how this `CustomInput` component is used

Comment: its used in a grid <Grid item xs={8}>
                <CustomInput
                  type="text"
                  onChange={props.handleChange}
                  onBlur={props.handleBlur}
                  value={props.values.search}
                  id="outlined-size-small"
                  defaultValue=""
                  variant="outlined"
                  size="small"
                  name="search"
                  label="Search"
                  disabled={props.isSubmitting}
                />
              </Grid>